# What do you test when changing parts

Tags: testing, test, replacement

Let's say some parts within one of your products are discontinued. You already have a replacement that seems to fit from specifications. What tests do you usually conduct to verify proper operation? Long time test over temperature? Just a few test routines on the desktop?

I am currently in charge to define which tests should be done and I am searching for advice and when possible literature sources adressing the question above.

Thank you very much

Comment: What was wrong with the tests you used to determine whether the original component was suitable in the first place? Just use those.

Comment: I am new in this company and the tests usually made are quite ... few. I just wanne hear what other usually invest in the testing

Comment: Don't you first need to know the key parameters that are more important before you can design tests? I'd assume that this was documented when the product was designed.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I just realized it boils down to work out the key parameters by myself to effectivly define the test routine.

Comment: @NoiseEngineer Something isn't right here. If the product is so important that you have to formally test and document tests for replacement components then some requirements and testing procedures MUST have been done during the design of the original product with the original part. Are you a student on a summer job that has just been given something to occupy your time? When I was one I was given a similar job and I was told all the tests to do it on the replacement part.

Comment: It depends what the part is and what does it do in the circuit. It also depends if the circuit is a pacemaker, space rocket or toy. There is no general answer. @DKNguyen Sometime a part is there because it is recommended by some example design, e.g. a common mode choke on a data line to make a design compliant with a standard, e.g. USB. In such a case there usually is no way of knowing why that part was originally selected and chanses of getting an answer from chip manufacturer is very slim, and re-evaluating if a design is compliant to a standard is very expensive and time consuming.

Comment: "I am new in this company and the tests usually made are quite ... few." - perhaps they are few because few tests are needed, or perhaps the company is just relying on the components meeting their specs. How much testing you need to do depends on how closely the replacement matches the original and how tolerant the circuit is of differences - and how much money the company is prepared to pay for testing. If you want more detailed advice then tell us what part is being substituted with what, and what role it plays in the product.

Comment: @Justme I'm not talking about tests on the component itself. I'm talking about just testing the entire board with the new component in it. Surely, if there are any tests to be run at all then there are at least tests run by manufacturing before each board goes out the door

Comment: Thank you all for contributing to my question. I think i can better judge how much effort we have to put in the testing individually. And I realized that my question is too generic to get a specific answer. I guess I just wanted to hear some people with little more experience than me and surely I did. There is no specific part to be replaced. It's more that the company did very poor testing (and documenting) and now pays the bill in some ways. Thats why the company wanted to formalized the testing processes a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments to my question, I just realized: There is no generic answer to the question. It depends much on the key parameters of the product, the importance of the part and product and how good replacements meet the specification.

Comment: ... and whether there is an adequate specification in the first place.